# AnyConnect to OpenConnect

Tags: networking, vpn, rsa

I'm using Cisco AnyConnect on Windows with a RSA softToken for a VPN connection to my office, and I can connect just fine. I have root access to the Windows box, and  can run Wireshark or any other utility at home to capture traffic. How can I connect my Linux laptop to the office using VPN? (Linux is not supported by IT, hence my need to go shadow-IT.)

Are there common gotchas with such a setup to be aware of?

Comment: Check out this guide: https://faq.oit.gatech.edu/content/how-do-i-install-cisco-anyconnect-client-linux